# SqlLiteDatabaseLockedException in android database helper class

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite

i've a helper class that manages all the database queries throughout my application. Its a singleton class and a getInstance() method.

```
public static MasterDatabase getInstance() {
    if (_masterDb == null) {
        _masterDb = new MasterDatabase();
    }
    return _masterDb;

}
```

Though i've taken care that only one instance of this class will be created, i get the **SqlLiteDatabaseLockedException** with the message that the database is locked. I thought of implementing **Double-checked Locking** technique but it appears that it may brake in multicore environments. So, what is the best implementation that will ensure that this exception wont repeat in my application.

**NOTE:** The other transaction methods(insert,delete,..) are not synchronised.

Question2 : Will making the transaction methods synchronised do good?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using android-s **DatabaseHelper** the database may already be opened by DatabaseHelper.

Try this

```
private static DatabaseHelper _myDatabaseHelper = null;

public static MasterDatabase getInstance() {
    if (_myDatabaseHelper == null) {
        _myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper();
    }
    return _myDatabaseHelper..getWritableDatabase();
}
```